# Thumbnail generation time

Tags: php, image, image-processing, loading

**Idea**
I have a function that checks to see if a thumbnail exists in `cache` folder for a particular image. If it does, it returns the path to that thumbnail. If it does not, it goes ahead and generates the thumbnail for the image, saves it in the `cache` folder and returns the path to it instead.

**Problem**
Let's say I have 10 images but only 7 of them have their thumbnails in the `cache` folder. Therefore, the function goes to generation of thumbnails for the rest 3 images. But while it does that, all I see is a blank, white loading page. The idea is to display the thumbnails that are already generated and then generate the ones that do not exist.

**Code**

```
$images = array(
        "http://i49.tinypic.com/4t9a9w.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/p2S1n.jpg",
        "http://i49.tinypic.com/l9tow.jpg",
        "http://i45.tinypic.com/10di4q1.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/PnefW.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/EqakI.jpg",
        "http://i46.tinypic.com/102tl09.jpg",
        "http://i47.tinypic.com/2rnx6ic.jpg",
        "http://i50.tinypic.com/2ykc2gn.jpg",
        "http://i50.tinypic.com/2eewr3p.jpg"
    );

function get_name($source) {
    $name = explode("/", $source);
    $name = end($name);
    return $name;
}

function get_thumbnail($image) {
    $image_name = get_name($image);
    if(file_exists("cache/{$image_name}")) {
        return "cache/{$image_name}";
    } else {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        if($width > $height) {
            $y = 0;
            $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
            $smallest_side = $height;
        } else {
            $x = 0;
            $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
            $smallest_side = $width;
        }

        $thumb_size = 200;
        $thumb_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb_image, $thumb, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumb_size, $thumb_size, $smallest_side, $smallest_side);

        imagejpeg($thumb_image, "cache/{$image_name}");

        return "cache/{$image_name}";
    }
}

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo "<img src='" . get_thumbnail($image) . "' />";
}
```

Comment: Don't generate thumbs preemptively. Redirect requests to non-existant thumbs to a PHP script that would generate them when they are needed.

Comment: @DCoder: I see. If possible, could you give me an coded example? I have no idea how to do what you just said. #Beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @DCoder's comment, what you could do is;

- If the thumb exists in the cache, return the URL just as you do now. This will make sure that thumbs that are in the cache will load quickly.
- If the thumb does *not* exist in the cache, return an URL similar to `/cache/generatethumb.php?http://i49.tinypic.com/4t9a9w.jpg` where the script `generatethumb.php` generates the thumbnail, saves it in the cache and returns the thumbnail. Next time, it will be in the cache and the URL won't go through the PHP script.

Comment: +1 - exactly what I had in mind, with one caveat - I would prefer to generate a unique identifier for each image and pass *that* to `generatethumb.php` instead of the full URL, or use a domain whitelist. Passing the full URL can give you "interesting" results if someone requests `http://yoursite.com/cache/generatethumb.php?http://yoursite.com/cache/generatethumb.php?http://yoursite.com/cache/generatethumb.php...`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This is precisely what I wanted to do. Thanks to @DCoder as well. Though I have another problem: Once the thumbnail is generated and saved in the directory, it shows a [X] symbol in it's place on the webpage (that symbol referring to "image not found"). What would be the a good way to remedy this?

Comment: @DCoder Good point, blindly fetching the URL without any kind of control is not a good thing. At the _very_ least, you should check that the URL requests an image type, like a jpg.

Comment: @Rafay That's why the script should return the generated thumbnail as a result, the browser will expect an image returned when the script is accessed.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: That is what the script does. I even send the header `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg")`. Still, no avail.

Comment: @Rafay Try saving the result and double checking that there are no PHP warnings/output inserted into the image stream. Sounds like the image is corrupt in some way.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I have figured it out. I was under the idea that imagejpg() function also outputs the image when passed with the second argument (that is to save the file). I fixed it by outputting the image, and then saving it with the same function. Thank you for all your help! :)